# NetLogo plotting - how to display tick marks on y axis?

Tags: plot, netlogo

I'm plotting percentage data on the yaxis in a netlogo plot. 
So the range of `y` is always `[0,1]`. 

I would like to display tick marks on the `y` axis at say `[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]`, simply to make it visually appealing.

Is this possible at all, or am I left to view min and max only and peer into it to actually make out the value?

I'm thinking that this is not possible since the plot when created asks for only `Ymin` and `Ymax`, but please prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Netlogo does not have such built in functionality.

It is possible to accomplish the task by drawing with the available plotting commands:
plot-pen-down
plot-pen-up
plotxy
...more can be seen in the netlogo dictionary.